# Create a "switch" macro to renew command based on its arguments

Tags: macros, luatex

I'm wondering why this doesn't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\testbasic}{BASIC}
\newcommand{\testfirst}{FIRST}
\newcommand{\testsecond}{SECOND}
\newcommand{\test}{\testbasic}

\newcommand{\switch}[1]{
  \directlua{
    tex.sprint([[\noexpand\renewcommand{\noexpand\test}{\noexpand\test#1}]])
  }
}

\begin{document}

\test

\switch{first}

\test

\switch{second}

\test

\switch{basic}

\test

\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\test ->\test 
              first
l.20 \test
```

So apparently lua output is `\renewcommand{\test}{\test}` when I expected it to be `\renewcommand{\test}{\testfirst}`

Isn't `tex.sprint` supposed to handle cases like this?

Is there a fix in my case?

Is there a better way to do it, with or without lua?

Bonus question: can I avoid all these `\noexpand` to produce clearer code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially doing the same as

```
\newcommand\switch[1]{\renewcommand{\test}{\test#1}}
```

which of course cannot work, because `\test` is a token by itself, so when you do `\switch{first}` the effect is doing

```
\renewcommand{\test}{\test first}
```

which of course will produce an infinite loop when `\test` is expanded.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\testbasic}{BASIC}
\newcommand{\testfirst}{FIRST}
\newcommand{\testsecond}{SECOND}
\newcommand{\test}{\testbasic}

\newcommand{\switch}[1]{%
  \directlua{
    tex.sprint([[\noexpand\renewcommand{\noexpand\test}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname test#1\endcsname}]])
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\test

\switch{first}

\test

\switch{second}

\test

\switch{basic}

\test

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the output]

You can achieve the same result with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \switch #1
 {
  \cs_set:Npx \test { \exp_not:c {test#1} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\testbasic}{BASIC}
\newcommand{\testfirst}{FIRST}
\newcommand{\testsecond}{SECOND}
\newcommand{\test}{\testbasic}

\begin{document}

\test

\switch{first}

\test

\switch{second}

\test

\switch{basic}

\test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mmm thanks! `\csname` is what I have to look into. I thought lua was a good way to get around this but as you pointed out, `\newcommand\switch[1]{\renewcommand{\test}{\csname test#1\endcsname}}` will do the job equally.

Comment: @nicoco Not fully the same: with the `\directlua` approach the final effect is like doing `\renewcommand{\test}{\testfirst]` so with an expansion step less when `\test` is called.